# chown increases docker image size

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have a dockerfile which is based on `openjdk:8u151-jre-alpine3.7` which works perfectly fine. The containers used to run as root user.

I wanted to modify it to use an user called 'app'.

```
# Add new user
RUN adduser -D -u 1000 app
ENV USER_HOME=/home/app
WORKDIR $USER_HOME
```

then i have few COPY commands

```
COPY dirA dirA
COPY dirB dirB
```

in the image all these dirA and dirB owned by root. so, i add chwon statement.
adding below statement in the dockerfile increases the size by `300MB`.

```
# chown all the files by app user
RUN chown -R app:app $USER_HOME
USER app
```

What is really going on? How to reduce the size by owning the files as app user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I was able to reduce the size by 300MB with below statement

```
COPY --chown=app:app dirA dirA
COPY --chown=app:app dirB dirB
```

Comment: This isn't an answer - this is you solving the problem you had before you asked the question.

Comment: @Makoto, that is part of the question. anyone who face similar issue could benefit with this.